# Move data if field is not empty

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro, where I'd like a row to be moved if the value in cell 1 (column A) is not empty. I've tried with below, but it doesn't work. It still leaves some non-blank rows behind.

Below is only some of the macro.

```
item1 = Cells(matchline, 1).Value
If (item1 <> "") Then
Sheets("X_Data").Cells(matchline, 1).EntireRow.Copy
```

Comment: You need to post more code than that, and describe more clearly your goal and what happens. Your code only copies a row, not moves it (or anything else).

Comment: `If (item1 <> "") ` tests if `item` is not a null string. Therefore the first question is if `item1` is a string at all. `item1 = Cells(matchline, 1).Value`. Of course, `Cells(matchline, 1).Value` is a variant and therefore might be a string. It is very likely that Excel can coerce `Value` into a string. I can't think of a situation when this might not be so but your test is adventurous. You shouldn't be surprised that it fails occasionally. Try `If Len(Trim(Cells(matchline, 1).Value)) Then` instead. Omit the intermediate use of `item1`.